# Are the following contradictions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following:

$p\to (q\land p)$

$p\to \neg (q\land p)$

I am asked if they are contradictions, can someone explain what that means exactly.

I did a truth table for both, and if `p` is True, then both equations are True, does this imply that they are not contradictions? Or, does contradiction simply mean that only one row in the truth table must differ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can call this "equation". Also, if p and q are true, then ¬(p^q) is false. So p -> ¬(p^q) is false, in this case you have one false and one true, not both true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not contradictions because (1) neither statement is a tautology or contradiction in its own right, and (2) the statements' truth values are not diametrically opposed (i.e., they are not opposites).

Answer (score 3):

> I did a truth table for both, and if p is `True`, then both equations are `True`,

Wrong.   An implication holds true only if the consequent is true whenever the antecedent is.   Yet if $p$ is true then the consequents of the two statements cannot both be true.

The two statements have the following equivalences.
$$p\to (q\wedge p) \iff \neg p \vee q
\\[2ex]
p\to \neg (q\wedge p) \iff \neg p \vee \neg q$$

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
p & q & p\wedge q & p\to (p\wedge q) & p\to \neg(p\wedge q) \\ \hline
  &   &           & \neg p\vee q    & \neg p\vee \neg q \\ \hline
T & T & T         & T                & F \\
T & F & F         & F                & T \\
F & T & F         & T                & T \\
F & F & F         & T                & T \\
\end{array}}$$

However, since it is *possible* for the two statements to both be true for some $p,q$, then these two statements do *not* contradict each other.

Two statements contradict each other only if their truth evaluations are opposed for *all* possible values of their variables.

Comment: (+1) Really dig that use of $\LaTeX$ there (and good insights too of course). :)

Comment: whoops, what I meant to write was when both p are assigned F then they are true, but thanks for the answer it was helpful